# how to receive extra parameters in web api request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httprequest, request-headers

i am writing a web api call, apart from request parameters i also need to receive extra parameters e.g. language, deviceId etc, what is the best way to do this?

```
[GET("abc/{type}"), HttpGet]    
public HttpResponseMessage GetValues(int type, int page = 1)
{ 
int totalPages = 0; 
var d= Getvalues2(type, Settings.PageSize, page, out totalPages); 
if (d == null) { return NotFound();} 
return Ok(d)
```

Comment: you can accept such params in query string or route parameters

Comment: please post the code of your actionresult so others are in better position to understand ur question

Comment: i am already receiving values in routing params, issue is every request contains that extra params, so i do not want to update each api call for these parameters. looking for a better way

Comment: in that case you can push those params in querystring. That way you can avoid re-writing your routes but you still have to change signatures of you action methods and obviously the inner functionality

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post help:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods

Using HTTP POST instead, and JObject to receive extra parameters.